# How to extract certain tags and replace others from XML with SimpleXML

Tags: php, xml, parsing, text, replace

I'm writing my own Blog in PHP, I want to be able to write posts in Markdown display the results in HTML, I also need to do a few custom things with the HTML.

There is a simple script that can convert Markdown into HTML however I need to do some things about the HTML once it's done:

1. I need to replace all HTML symbols inside a pre tag by using the htmlentities() function. (In my blog I post about code including HTML, I only want to display this HTML and not parse it in the browser).
2. I need to extract all the plain text so I can create excerpts that don't include image tags or half tags (or pieces of code inside a pre for that matter) at the end.

I've thought I had a solution for problem 2 by using the following code:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<xml>' . $html . '</xml>');
```

$xml now looks something like:

```
<xml>
  <p>some random text</p>
  <img src='image.jpg'>
  <p>some random text</p>
</xml>
```

this extracts all the text:

```
foreach($xml->{'p'} as $p){
echo $p . '<hr>';
}
```

This works however I also want to it include all the text found in ul's and ol's (in the same order as they appear in the XML. I've searched for a way to loop over all the children of $xml but I can't find how to check if the element is either a p, ul or ol.

And I can't find a way to solve problem 1 because I don't know how to replace content in the XML object, but leaving everything else intact. (Or am I missing something completly obvious?)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replacing end div tags using preg_replace_callback function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8772348/replacing-end-div-tags-using-preg-replace-callback-function) - see as well: http://php.net/dom_import_simplexml

Comment: There are many more, other question and answers that cover that as well. I suggest you use the search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of searching I could not find exactly what I was looking for using XML parsing, besides that I needed a couple of other features. I solved the problem with REGEX since all the HTML is generated by me.

So the solution provided here solves the problem of my original problems + some more.

This function takes a piece of content (string) and returns a couple of strings:

- md = the same as the content with the anglebrackets inside pre's changed to their html entity (I blog about HTML, but in my *edit post* screen I don't want the html inside pre's being parsed.
- html = everything outside pre's is Markdown'd and every htmlchar inside the pre's is changed to their html entity.
- excerpt = the text shrinked close to 300 chars, without any pre tags (or the content of those), without markdown syntax or html tags.
- meta = same as excerpt for 160 chars.

  ```
  function prepareContent($content) {

      // I use this instead of htmlentities for the plain text, this prevents HTML to be parsed inside the edit screen
      // all HTML is served with htmlentities instead
      function removeAngleBrackets($str) {
          $str = str_replace('<','&lt;',$str);
          $str = str_replace('>','&gt;',$str);
          return $str;
      }

      $segments = preg_split('/(<\/?pre.*?>)/', $content, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);

      // STATE MACHINE
      // borrowed from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1278491/howto-encode-texts-outside-the-pre-pre-tag-with-htmlentities-php#answer-1278575

      // this breaks when I nest pre's in pre's (unless I escape the <pre> myself), could be fixed though

      // $state = 0 if outside of a pre
      // $state = 1 if inside of a pre
      $state = 0;

      $plaintext = '';
      $html = '';
      $preless = '';

      // $html, $plaintext and $preless are all written in here
      foreach ($segments as &$segment) {
          if ($state == 0) {
              if (preg_match('#<pre[^>]*>#i',$segment)) {
                  //this is the pre opening tag
                  $state = 1; 
                  $html .= $segment;
                  $plaintext .= $segment;
              } else {
                  //this is outside the pre tag
                  $plaintext .= $segment;
                  $markdown = Markdown($segment);
                  $html .= $markdown;
                  $preless .= $markdown;
              }
          } else if ($state == 1) {
              if ($segment == '</pre>') {
                  //this is the pre closing tag
                  $state = 0;
                  $html .= $segment;
                  $plaintext .= $segment;
              } else {
                  //this is inside the pre tag
                  $plaintext .= removeAngleBrackets($segment);
                  // first encode &gt; to > so I can re encode it together with other chars
                  // else we get double encoding like: $amp;gt;
                  $enti = html_entity_decode($segment);
                  $html .= htmlspecialchars($enti, ENT_QUOTES);
              }
          }
      }

      $arr['html'] = SmartyPants($html);
      $arr['md'] = $plaintext;

      //                      the excerpt & meta

      // remove all html tags (markdown is already converted to HTML)
      $tagless = strip_tags($preless);

      function shrinkText($str, $limit) {
          $strlen = strlen($str);
          if($strlen > $limit) {
              $pos = strpos($str, ' ', $limit);
              if($strlen > $pos) {
                  $result = substr($str,0,$pos);
              }
          }
          return $result ? $result : $str;
      }

      // I need to smartypants the excerpt to
      $excerpt = shrinkText($tagless, 275)  . ' (...)';
      $arr['excerpt'] = SmartyPants($excerpt);

      $arr['meta'] = shrinkText($tagless, 160);

      return $arr;
  }
  ```